# Is it possible to use standart View in custom LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas

I would like to add TextView and EditView into my custom LinearLayout programmatically.
But I don't know how.
Something like this (that doesn't work):

```xml
<com.custom.FavoritesViewer
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/favoritesViewer">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hello"/>
</com.custom.FavoritesViewer>
```

and my custom layout

```java
public class FavoritesViewer extends LinearLayout {

    private Bitmap fullImage;
    private int canvasWidth;
    private int canvasHeight;

    private final Paint paint = new Paint();

    public FavoritesViewer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setWillNotDraw(false);
        initializeCanvasSize(context);
    }

    private void initializeCanvasSize(Context context) {
        final Pair<Integer, Integer> screenSize = Utils.getScreenSize(context);
        canvasWidth = screenSize.first;
        canvasHeight = screenSize.second;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        setMeasuredDimension(canvasWidth, canvasHeight / 3);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas cvs) {
        if (fullImage == null) {
            fullImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvasWidth, canvasHeight / 3,     Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(fullImage);
            paint.reset();
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#AA000000"));
            canvas.drawRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight / 3, paint);
        }
        cvs.drawBitmap(fullImage, 0, 0, null);
    }

}
```

So I have a canvas (like background) and I would like to add some standart Views on top. I cannot add it on onDraw.

Is it any way to add View into custom Layout?

**EDITTED**

I need to implement some special UI with buttons. I want to wrap this in one component. I draw that UI on canvas and somehow should add buttons (It's enough for me to add simple ImageButton, not to draw an image and emulate button's behaviour). That's why I selected Layout as container and need to add Views programmatically.

Comment: You do realize there is the addView() method? Maybe read some documentation ... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View, int, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)

Answer (score 0):

As long as you call through to super (probably super.onDraw()), I imagine the parent class will draw the views you add as expected. It looks like you're just overriding onDraw, which would prevent the parent LinearLayout class from rendering it's content (like the TextView).

Try commenting out your onDraw method first, and see if the LinearLayout behaves as expected.

Also, what's the goal of the Custom Layout? There may be a better way to achieve your goal.